# tikz bubble plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to generate a bubble plot which look like the following.

[image]

However, what I exactly want is something like the following plot.

[image]

The following is what I tried.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
          width=4.5in,
          height=3.5in,
          xtick=data,
          symbolic x coords = {A,B,C,D},
          scale only axis,
          xticklabel style={rotate=45,anchor=east,align=center},
          xticklabels={Social media,Remote sensing,CCTV,WSN and IoT},
       ]
      \addplot[%
          scatter=true,
          only marks,
          mark=*,
          point meta=explicit,
          visualization depends on = {0.5*\thisrow{Val} \as \perpointmarksize},
          scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={/tikz/mark size=\perpointmarksize},
      ] table [x={x},y={Yval},meta index=2] {
x  Algorithm Val Yval
A  CNN  2 2
A  RNN  8 4
B  RNN  15 4
C  RNN  10 4
D  CNN  4 2
};      
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are already very close, and this may take another iteration since I obviously do not know which column is to go where.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
          width=4.5in,
          height=3.5in,
          xtick=data,
          symbolic x coords = {A,B,C,D},
          symbolic y coords = {CNN,RNN,AE,AE},
          ytick distance=1,ymax=AE,
          scale only axis,
          xticklabel style={rotate=45,anchor=east,align=center},
          xticklabels={Social media,Remote sensing,CCTV,WSN and IoT},
       ]
      \addplot[%
          scatter=true,
          only marks,
          mark=*,
          point meta=explicit,
          fill opacity=0.5,text opacity=1,
          visualization depends on = {2*\thisrow{Val} \as \perpointmarksize},
          scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={
          /tikz/mark size=\perpointmarksize,/tikz/mark options={draw=none}},
          nodes near coords*,
          nodes near coords style={text=white,font=\sffamily,anchor=center},
      ] table [x={x},y={Algorithm},meta index=2] {
x  Algorithm Val Yval
A  CNN  2 2
A  RNN  8 4
B  RNN  15 4
C  RNN  10 4
D  CNN  4 2
};      
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ Schrödinger's cat: Excellent! This is exactly what I wanted :).